# $X \equiv 1 \pmod{20} \land X \equiv 1 \pmod{22} \iff X \equiv 1 \pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(20,22)}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, chinese-remainder-theorem

$X \equiv 1 \pmod{20} \land X \equiv 1 \pmod{22} \iff X \equiv 1 \pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(20,22)}$

I dont understand how I would go about this proof. I am trying to use this to solve a CRT-problem with these two numbers, which are not coprime. I know, that you could split $20 = 2^2 \cdot 5$ and $22 = 2 \cdot 11$ in its prime factors. I know, that you could rewrite as $20 \mid X - 1$ and $22 \mid X - 1$. But I dont get it even if wikipedia and other articles act like you can see it directly. I appreciate every hint.

Comment: Asked very recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725299/how-can-i-show-that-x-equiv1-pmod20-and-x-equiv1-pmod22-iff-x-equiv1-p/)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show that: $x\equiv1\pmod{20}$ and $x\equiv1\pmod{22}$ iff $x\equiv1\pmod{220}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725299/how-can-i-show-that-x-equiv1-pmod20-and-x-equiv1-pmod22-iff-x-equiv1-p)

Comment: This is practically the definition of LCM. The first says that $20$ is a factor of $X-1$ and the second that $22$ is a factor of $X-1.$ We have a general theorem that if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mid c.$

Comment: Alternative (simpler, but much less elegant) approach: $$x \equiv 1 \pmod{220} \implies x \equiv 1 \pmod{20} ~~\text{and}~~ x \equiv 1 \pmod{11}.$$  For the converse, $~x \equiv 1 \pmod{20}~$ implies that the least non-negative residue of $~x, \pmod{220}~$ must be some element in $~\{1,21,41,61,\cdots, 201\}.$  Of these $~11~$ residues, which one(s) are congruent to $~1 \pmod{11}?$